# Select Dropdown menu value or text using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to grab the value of my dropdown list and store it in a variable using Javascript. I have searched several articles and have mostly found JQuery methods (methods that have not worked for me, I could be implementing them incorrectly), but I would prefer using a pure Javascript method.

Solution reviewed:
[Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript)
This solution using an `<option>` HTML tag as where I am using a `<div>` tag.

I have also implemented a JQuery function that allows the selected value in the dropdown to replace the button text, could this be intervening with my ability to implement the functionality of grabbing that value?

All solutions I seem to be looking for contain the `option` tag.

> JS:

```
let valueElement = document.querySelector(".dropdown-menu");
let strUsers = valueElement.option[valueElement.selectedIndex].text;
console.log(`User Selected: ${strUsers}`)
```

I should probably not be using `.option`

> HTML:

```
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          User
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-value="Admin-0">Admin-0</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-value="Admin-1">Admin-1</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-value="Admin-2">Admin-2</a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Do you want to get the value contained in the 'a' tag?

Comment: use: `valueElement.addEventListener('click', event => {if(event.target.classList.contains('dropdown-item')) {console.log(event.target.innerText)}})`

Comment: This solved my problem thank you. I cannot mark this as the Answer as it is a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a custom select dropdown, you can not use the `selectIndex` property because the `selectIndex` is only available on `<select>` element, also options property is only available on `<select>`

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_selectedindex.asp

You need to do something different, you can append an event listener on `<a>` inside your dropdown and put a class that tell you if user select

I hope it helps